# Routes error with redmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working with Redmine 2.4.5 and I've installed the better_gantt_chart plugin to not change the original Gantt.
I'm making a js file to improve the plugin with drag and drop etc...
Here is my problem : when I'm trying to call a url with ajax to use a controller that I've created it's impossible, and I suppose that's because the better_gantt_char plugin is using patches and hooks but I don't really know.

Here is one of the codes I've tried:

**routes.rb**

```
put 'projects/wine-investment-network/issues/gantt', :to => 'better_gantt_charts#update_data'

match 'projects/wine-investment-network/issues/gantt'=> 'better_gantt_charts#update_data', via: :put
```

**drag_drop.js**

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: project_name + "/issues/gantt",    
      success: function() { /* ... */ },
      error: function() { /* ... */ }
    });
```

**better_gantt_charts_controller**

```
class BetterGanttChartsController < ApplicationController

unloadable

def update_data
...
end
```

**And here is the error**

```
Started PUT "/projects/wine-investment-network/issues/gantt" for 192.168.21.66 at 2014-06-17 12:02:00 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant BetterGanttChartsController):
```

Comment: You sure you getting this url: projects/wine-investment-network/issues/gantt

Comment: Yes, this is the firebug console
drag_d...2999188 (ligne 2)
PUT http://192.168.21.139/projects/wine-investment-network/issues/gantt
404 Not Found
   And of course, I replace my "wine-investment-network" by ":project_id" when i want it work for all projects

Comment: why does the controller have `unloadable`? (this does not cause the error, just uncommon). Do you close `BetterGanttChartsController` properly, maybe you forgot a 'end' at the end of the file. run `rake routes` from the application form to see all the routes, if none from the `BetterGanttChartsController` show up, you have bad syntax in this file probably.